# The difference between the two functions in Scala,the foreach cannot accumulate the outer Map

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm a fresh learner, I want to count the number of different words from a file.

**This works fine**

```
val filePath = "C:\\Users\\76274\\Desktop\\yaml.txt"
def exercise2(file:String): HashMap[String,Int] ={
  Source.fromFile(file).getLines().foldLeft(HashMap[String,Int]())(
  (result,str) =>
    str.split("\\W+").foldLeft(result)(
      (result,word) => result + (word.toLowerCase -> (result.getOrElse(word.toLowerCase,0) + 1)))) 
}
```

**And this will return an empty Map**

```
val filePath = "C:\\Users\\76274\\Desktop\\yaml.txt"
def exercise2(file:String): HashMap[String,Int] ={
Source.fromFile(file).getLines().foldLeft(HashMap[String,Int]()){
  (result,str) => {
    str.split("\\W+").foreach(word => {
    result + (word.toLowerCase -> (result.getOrElse(word.toLowerCase,0) + 1))
    println(result)
  })}
  result
}
}
```

I don't know why the later one doesn't work. As a `Java` programmer, I think it should work fine, too. I hope you can explain it, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the second one does not work, is because the `+` method isn't really adding elements to the **Map**, but instead it is creating a new Map with the given element added/updated - [scaladoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/HashMap.html#+[V1%3E:V](kv:(K,V1)):scala.collection.mutable.Map[K,V1]).

If you want the second one to work using a **MUTABLE** map, you can use the `+=` method - [scaladoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/HashMap.html#+=(kv:(A,B)):HashMap.this.type). BTW, if you're going for a mutable solution I wouldn't bother to use fold in the first level neither, but instead another foreach.

However, In Scala we prefer to be immutable, that's why we would go for the first one with an **IMMUTABLE** map.

**PS:** Not really related to this, but unless you really need it to be a HashMap, prefer the `Map` trait *(which by default is immutable)* or `scala.collection.mutable.Map` *(which is mutable)*. Also to create an empty collection is more common to call the `empty` method, instead of an empty *apply* `()`. e.g `Map.empty[String, Int]`.

Comment: You are right, when to use mutable map, the second one can work,too.Now,I know the true reason,thank you!